# Hi , how can i add a keyframe every time a score is being updated from a sports API so the score blinks for a couple of seconds if it changes?

Tags: javascript, html

how can i add a keyframe every time a score is being updated from a sports API so the score blinks for a couple of seconds if it changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need javascript to add class then remove it after a few seconds.
Like so:

```js
function update_score() {
  var elem = document.querySelector(".score");
  elem.classList.add("active");
  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.remove("active")
  }, 1000)
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.score {
  font-size: 32px;
}

.active {
  animation: target-fade 1s;
}


@keyframes target-fade {
  from {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  to {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<span class="score">82</span><br>

<button onclick="update_score()">update score</button>
```

Comment: Thak you - it worked perfectly !!!